# Elasticsearch Became case sensitive after add synonym analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

After I added synonym analyzer to my_index, the index became case-sensitive

I have one property called `nationality` that has `synonym analyzer`. But it seems that this property become `case sensitive` because of the synonym analyzer.

Here is my `/my_index/_mappings`

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "items": {
        "properties": {
          .
          .
          .
          "nationality": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            },
            "analyzer": "synonym"
          },
          .
          .
          .
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inside the index, i have word `India COUNTRY`. When I try to search `India nation` using the command below, I will get the result.

```
POST /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "nationality": "India nation"
    }
  }
}
```

But, when I search for `india` (notice the letter `i` is lowercase), I will get nothing.
My assumption is, this happend because i put `uppercase` filter before the `synonym`. I did this because the synonyms are uppercased. So the query `India` will be `INDIA` after pass through this filter.

Here is my `/my_index/_settings`

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "my_index",
        "similarity": {
          "default": {
            "type": "BM25",
            "b": "0.9",
            "k1": "1.8"
          }
        },
        "creation_date": "1647924292297",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "synonym": {
              "type": "synonym",
              "lenient": "true",
              "synonyms": [
                "NATION, COUNTRY, FLAG"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "synonym": {
              "filter": [
                "uppercase",
                "synonym"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "version": {
          "created": "6080099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way so I can make this property still case-insensitive. All the solution i've found only shows that I should only either set all the text inside `nationality` to be lowercase or uppercase. But how if I have uppercase & lowercase letters inside the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you apply synonym filter after adding your data into index?

**If so**, probably "India COUNTRY" phrase was indexed exactly as "India COUNTRY". When you sent a match query to index, your query was analyzed and sent as "INDIA COUNTRY" because you have uppercase filter anymore, it is matched because you are using match query, it is enough to match one of the words. "COUNTRY" word provide this.

But, when you sent one word query "india" then it is analyzed and converted to "INDIA" because of your uppercase filter but you do not have any matching word on your index. You just have a document contains "India COUNTRY".

My answer has a little bit assumption. I hope that it will be useful to understand your problem.

Comment: Yes, I also assuming that is happening here. So I think another approach is to set all document in my index to be uppercase. But do you have other solution for this? Thanks

Comment: I already tried to point your problem by first sentence. You need to create your mapping includes filter, analyzer etc. first then you will put your data to index. So both your data and query will be analyzed with same approach.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. I did not realize that it has the impact to the data inside the index. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution!

I didn't realize that the filter that I applied in the `settings` is applicable while updating and searching the data. At first, I did this step:

1. Create index with synonym filter
2. Insert data
3. Add `uppercase` before synonym filter

By doing that, the `uppercase` filter is not applied to my data. What I should've done are:

1. Create index with `uppercase` & `synonym` filter (pay attention to the order)
2. Insert data
   Then the filter will be applied to my data.